# ElasticSearch - Delete an Index using Java HighLevel HTTP Client

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Previously using ElasticSearch Transport API, I have deleted an index and its data using the below line of program.

```
            DeleteByQueryAction.INSTANCE.newRequestBuilder(client).source(indexName).get();
```

We are migrated from Transport Client API to HTTP Client API now. Unfortunately this is not supported in ES HighLevel HTTP client API as for as I know. Is there a way to delete an index using HTTP client?

**Edited:** 
I am using ES Rest client API version 5.6.4. Deleting an index is available in the latest 6.x versions. I am looking for deleting the index in version 5.6.4. Thanks

Comment: What about this? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-delete-index.html

Comment: @Val Thanks for the reply. Forgot to mention the version I am using. Please  check the edited part of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then I suggest simply making a DELETE call on your index using the low-level REST API, that'd do the trick

```
Response response = restClient.performRequest("DELETE", "/" + indexName);
```

Note that you don't need to use the Delete by query API for deleting an index.

Comment: It is working fine for deleting the particular index. But after deletion when I try to fetch data using that same index name I am getting some unexpected data instead of the message "that index not present" or something else. @Val do you have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: @Bran what message do you get?

Comment: Instead of any error or warning it returns some documents which did not come under that deleted index. NOTE : I have given only that index name(the deleted one) while searching.

Comment: I suggest you create a new question describing your exact problem, this thread is closed and it's not a good idea to cram another question in comments.